# Parsing a JSON file but not getting everything returned

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-places-api

I'm trying to parse a JSON file from Google Places API. I am trying to gather the vicinity address, the lng/lat coordinates, as well as the Place ID. On the page with the JSON file, my code is capturing more of the locations' information, but for some reason it is not getting the data from one of the locations. My code is:

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
for n in range(len(data['results'])):
  location = []
  address = data['results'][n]['vicinity']
  address = address[: address.find(", ")]
  coords_lat = str(data['results'][n]['geometry']['location']['lat'])
  coords_lat = coords_lat[:-4]
  coords_lng = str(data['results'][n]['geometry']['location']['lng'])
  coords_lng = coords_lng[:-4]
  place_id = data['results'][n]['place_id']
  location = [address, coords_lat, coords_lng, place_id]
  print location
```

But for one of the locations, my program is returning:
`...[u'C', '33.87', '-84.53', u'ChIJOUmV_jgX9YgRdN1sudI8yOI']...` instead of the full vicinity address for this location, `'C, 2976 Ask-Kay Dr, Smyrna'`.

[This is my python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0kAx.png)

[This is the API JSON page with one of the results I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvFJf.png)

[These are some of the lines my program is printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUHA1.png)

Comment: Please include the text. Links go dead, and the point of the site is not just to help you but people who have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Hi Jared, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I included the text of my code and the text of the erroneous output. What else do you suggest I include?

Comment: Please edit in the JSON rather than having it be externally linked. Although for what its worth, this question is easily in the top quartile for first posts on this site in terms of quality :)

Comment: I just didn't want to put too much unnecessary text in the actual question. I didn't want to deter anyone that could help from reading it because it was so lengthy. I will keep that in mind for my questions to come. Also, thanks for the support! (:

Comment: For SO questions you want to include everything necessary to reproduce the problem *and nothing more*. Minimal test case to repro usually includes some sample data along with current output and desired output, e.g. `my_function({"foo": 2}) prints {"foo": 4} but should be {"foo": 8}` along with the code for `my_function`. And no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to display `address` right after

```
address = data['results'][n]['vicinity']
```

before you edit it with

```
address = address[: address.find(", ")]
```

It might have to do with the `,` Characters in the text

> C, 2976 Ask-Kay Dr, Smyrna

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I realized that because there were multiple occurrences of the string ", " and I was using that string to slice, that the address was getting sliced before I wanted it to. I resolved this by using .rfind() instead of .find()